# Java overwriting file

Tags: java

I have a problem now. I created a simple pet hotel application and I wanted to implement a delete function so user can remove existing booking.

```
                              //the main one.
                              System.out.println("---------------------------");
                              System.out.println("Welcome to the delete menu:");
                              System.out.println("---------------------------");
                              Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                                System.out.println("Enter owner's first name");
                                String firstName = scanner.nextLine();
                                System.out.println("Enter owner's last name");
                                String lastName = scanner.nextLine();

                             delete(firstName, lastName);

                             //the delete class



public static void delete(String firstName, String lastName) throws Exception
{

    File inputFile = new File("BookingDetails.txt");   // Your file  
    File tempFile = new File("TempBooking.txt");// temp file
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
    String currentLine;
    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        if(currentLine.contains(firstName) && currentLine.contains(lastName)) 
        continue;
        writer.write(currentLine+"\n");
    }
        writer.close();
}
```

There's a booking file already existed
Which contains this details.

```
Abid Akmal 03/09/2013 0129928272 Checkup File 10 250.0 Dog
Zhi Kai 12/11/2013 1029918811 Grooming Pika 1 25.0 Rabbit
Vincent Che 12/03/2013 0129817711 Grooming Fleese 2 50.0 Dog
```

It's a user input so when user want to delete the record, they will input for example Zhi as first name and Kai as last name, after that
a new folder TempBooking.txt appear with the other two booking details that still exist But the original BookingDetails.txt folder also is still there with the original booking record.
My problem now what's the function to overwrite the file so the temp file (TempBooking.txt) will change to BookingDetails.txt.

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  3) BTW - do you have a *question*?  What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

either you delete `BookingDetails.txt` and rename `TempBooking.txt` to `BookingDetails.txt`.

or

write all your content from `TempBooking.txt` to `BookingDetails.txt`